# SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.Update() Performs Very Slowly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I am porting VB.Net 2 code (VS 2005) to VB.Net 4 (VS 2010).  So far things have been going relatively smooth.  However, in testing my new ported code, I came across a strange behavior.

In VS 2005 (.Net 2), I have a DataTable filled with data.  I then use a DataAdapter to send updates back to the SQL Server.  When I perform the  SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.Update() command, it execute in roughly 4 seconds.  The same code, on the same table in VS 2010 (.Net 4) runs in 1 Minute 17 Seconds.  This is completely unacceptable.  However, I have no clue as to *why* it is happening.  The .Update() method is an internal command, not one that I modified in any way.  It does not error out, it's just painfully slow.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there anyone out there that has heard or experienced this problem? No one has noticed a degredation of performance using .Net 4's SQLClient.SQLDataAdapter?

Comment: Not seen anything like that, turn the profiler on for old and new an compare the same operation, might give you some clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many months of working directly with Microsoft...a solution/answer was found.

I don't feel so bad because it took six different Microsoft programmers and almost six months of time to discover the answer.  Apparently, Visual Studio 2010's IDE behaves significantly different than it's Visual Studio 2005 counterpart. When running an application in the IDE, VS2010's hook into the running executable actually hinders the applications performance considerably. There is a hidden option (not found in the menu structure) to run the application without the debugger attached.  The hotkey is CTRL+F5. When the application is run in this mode, our performance issue vanished. It's such a silly and simple answer...but the two things that make me feel better is that VS2005 did not have this issue, the "run w/o debugger" options isn't listed in the menu at all, and it took six Microsoft programmers to determine this was the issue.

So for anyone else that seems to have this same issue...try CTRL+F5.  :-)